# How can we show this inequality?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Let $E$ be a nonempty set and $d,\rho,\rho_r$ be metrics on $E$ with $$d\le1+\beta\rho\tag1$$ for some $\beta\in(0,1]$. Assume there are $k,\delta>0$ such that $$d(x,y)=1+\beta\rho(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E\text{ with }\rho_r(x,y)\ge\delta\tag2$$ and $$d(x,y)\ge1+\beta k\tag3$$ for all $x,y\in E$ with $\rho(x,y)\ge k$ and $\rho_r(x,y)\ge\delta$.

> How can we show that $$1-\alpha+\alpha d(x,y)\le\underbrace{\left(\frac{1+\alpha\beta k}{1+\beta k}\right)}_{=:\:\alpha_1}d(x,y)\tag4$$ for all $x,y\in E$ with $\rho(x,y)\ge k$ and $\rho_r(x,y)\ge\delta$?

It guess we need to use $(3)$ to obtain $(4)$. But the only thing I'm able to obtain $$1-\alpha+\alpha d(x,y)\ge\alpha_1(1+\beta k)\tag5$$ and $$\alpha_1d(x,y)\ge1+\alpha\beta k\tag6$$ for all $x,y\in E$ with $\rho(x,y)\ge k$ and $\rho_r(x,y)\ge\delta$, which is not useful.

Comment: Usage of logic symbols would shorten your post. Instead of writing _for all_ you can just use $\forall$. It would be better even aesthetically, besides, symbols are often more readable and understandable to non-native English speakers.

Comment: @Fractal That's a matter of personal preference. I think it would be less aesthetic and look more complicated.

Comment: If it were so, mathematicians would've never introduced them in the first place. (:

Comment: @Fractal Use of quantifiers as you suggest is awful for readability. I am unaware of a single paper in mathematics that uses quantifiers instead of words as you suggest for this reason so this is even the standard in mathematics research. It is then strange to claim that having introduced them mathematicians have to use them since professional mathematicians **do not** use them in their papers.

Comment: And quantifier symbols should only be used with dummy variables, while words are used to define global variable that one will use several time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying both sides of the inequality you want to obtain by $1+\beta k$ and then removing $\alpha\beta kd(x,y)$, we see that it is equivalent to prove
$$
(1-\alpha) (1+\beta k) + \alpha d(x,y) \leq d(x,y)
$$
And this is exactly inequality (3) multiplied by $(1-\alpha)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew it was trivial. Do you see any reason (maybe in something I derived in the question) why we should need to restrict $\beta$ to belong to $(0,1)$? Everything should work for arbitrary $\beta\in[0,\infty)$ or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, everything work for $\beta\in[0,\infty)$ here.